# Why does the resource remain accessible after it has been released and the program does not crash?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
static inline string BoolToString(bool boolean_exp) {
    return boolean_exp? "True" : "False";
}
class Foo {
public:
    explicit Foo(int _size) noexcept : 
        my_resource(new int[_size]) {
        cout << "Foo obj init, at: " << this << ", my_resource at:" << my_resource <<endl;
        my_resource[0] = 1234567;
    }
    ~Foo() {
        cout << "A Foo instance at: " << this << " is finalizing; ";
        cout << "my_resource: " << my_resource << endl;
        delete[] my_resource;
        my_resource = nullptr;
    }

public:
    int *my_resource = nullptr;
};

void function_foo(Foo f) {
    cout << "function_foo() invoked" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Foo foo(20);
    function_foo(foo); // I think, foo's copy should released after function_foo() return-ed, my_resource should be nullptr;
    cout << "Is foo.my_resource released?: " << BoolToString(foo.my_resource == nullptr) << endl;
    cout << (*foo.my_resource) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, after the `function_foo` function is called in the main function, a shallow copy of foo is passed to `function_foo` as an argument, and that shallow copy should be destructured after `function_foo` is finished. After the function has finished running, the `my_resource` field in foo (declared in the main function) is still can be parsed and get value 1234567I would like to know why this is?

My idea is that although the memory resource pointed to by `my_resource` is freed when the temporary object is destructured, this memory resource is not reclaimed or not overwritten, so it can still be accessed in the **wrong** way.
Did the compiler did what it shouldn't have done?

By the way, I use clang++ as compiler and the development environment is windows.

compile: `clang++ file.cxx -o file.exe`
run: `./file`
Result:

```
Foo obj init, at: 0x61fdd8, my_resource at:0x1f1e90
function_foo() invoked
A Foo instance at: 0x61fdd0 is finalizing; my_resource: 0x1f1e90
is foo.my_resource released?: False
1234567
A Foo instance at: 0x61fdd8 is finalizing; my_resource: 0x1f1e90
```

Comment: "the compiler did what it shouldn't have done". No, **you** did what you shouldn't have done. The compiler didn't write an invalid program. You did. The compiler just compiled it.

Comment: *"Or rather, the compiler did what it shouldn't have done."* - the compiler isn't responsible for avoiding undefined behavior; that's *your* role. So yeah, failure detected, but it wasn't the compiler. C++ allows you tremendous latitude, including the ability to freely break the rules and step into undefined behavior. Doing so is on you. If someone told you your program *would crash* they're naïve. It *may* crash. It *may* not. It *may* do a lot of things. Thus the nature of UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After the function has finished running, the my_resource field in foo (declared in the main function) is still can be parsed and get value 1234567I would like to know why this is?

It is undefined behavior, so it may work if you are unlucky.

In typical C++ implementations, this has a good chance of not crashing, because the allocation is smaller than a page and allocators are not required to return the memory back to the operating system. This means your process still has the ability to read that address.

In addition, the compiler didn't decide to use the address for something else, so it just so happens that the value is still there.

Answer (score 1):

The memory resource *is* released, but that doesn't mean that it's gone! It's just marked as "free memory" and the next time something in your program tries to allocate memory it might be given that piece of memory. So, yeah... it's still there... for now... but you shouldn't rely on it, because you cannot predict what is going to happen to it in the future.

C++ doesn't bother to somehow "lock access" or even just "erase" the released memory because that would only take up CPU cycles for no tangible benefit. After you've released the memory, you're not supposed to touch it anyway.